# How to play media from an ArrayBuffer in Angular?

Tags: angular

I'm sending some data to from my back with nodeJS to Angular and everything is fine, the problem is that my media files doesn´t work first of all my code, I read and make the Blob file like this:

```
this.socket.on('nextQuestion', (data) => {

      switch(data.multimedia){
        case "image":
          const Iblob = new Blob([data.file], { type: 'image/*' });
          data.file = URL.createObjectURL(Iblob)
          break;
        case "audio":
          const Ablob = new Blob([data.file], { type: 'audio/*' });
          data.file = URL.createObjectURL(Ablob)
          break;
        case "video":
          const Vblob = new Blob([data.file], { type: 'video/*' });
          data.file = URL.createObjectURL(Vblob)
          break;
      }

this.question = data
}
```

As you can notice `this.question` is a global variable so it can be readed on the html, and this is how:

```
        <div class="audio" *ngIf="pregunta.multimedia == 'audio'">
          <audio controls>
            <source [src]="pregunta?.file" type="audio/*">
          </audio>
        </div>
        <div class="video" *ngIf="pregunta.multimedia == 'video'">
          <video controls width="400" height="300" #videoPlayer></video>
        </div>
        <div class="image" *ngIf="pregunta.multimedia == 'image'">
          <img [src]="pregunta?.file" alt="" type="image/*">
        </div>
```

The only thing that works is image, audio and video won´t work, in the next image I´ll show you mi data array, so if I was missing something you can help me:

[data array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZkFmG.png)

I´ve tried this:

Use a ElementRef to put the buffer that way but it doesn´t work, I only tried this to video

```
playVideo(arrayBuffer: ArrayBuffer) {
    const blob = new Blob([arrayBuffer], { type: 'video/*' });
    const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    const videoPlayer = this.videoPlayerRef.nativeElement;
    videoPlayer.src = blobUrl;
    videoPlayer.play();
  }
```

I don´t in what I´m wrong, in some google serach some people covert all the buffer string to base64, but I also readed that doing that it makes the quality of the video bad, so i´m really stuck.
Thank you for read.

Comment: Hi @user23755037, I add some way to accomplish it, but unfortunately cannot with arraybuffer sorry

Comment: If it helped you my answer, mark it as correct :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some probe to give you an answer:

Service:

First I tried to use "responseType: arrayBuffer" but when I tried to convert to base64 was different content so isn't work, and in this case I thought this should be did with another approach using "video parts transmission". so, I used responseType: 'text'.

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class VideosService {
private BASE_URL: string = 'http://localhost:3000'

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

getVideo() {
    return this.http.get(`${this.BASE_URL}/video`, {
        responseType: 'text',
    })
}

}
```

So Literally I get the base64 sended by my little node server:

```
 // Load the video file and convert it to Base64
    fs.readFile(videoPath, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        res.status(500).send('Error reading video file');
        return;
      }

      const base64Video = data.toString('base64');

      // Send the Base64 video data in the response
      res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','http://localhost:4200');
      res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'video/mp4');
      res.setHeader('Content-Length', base64Video.length);
      res.send(base64Video);
    });
```

So inside the component.ts:

I found another problem, with the  element, which if I modify the "source" didn't catch the update. So I had to create manually the elements and attach them the source. (Also, needs interaction to play it).

```
import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core'
import { AsyncPipe, CommonModule } from '@angular/common'
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router'
import { NestedComponent } from './nested/nested.component'
import { VideosService } from './videos.service'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs'

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    standalone: true,
    imports: [CommonModule, RouterOutlet, NestedComponent, AsyncPipe],
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrl: './app.component.scss',
})
export class AppComponent {
    @ViewChild('player') player!: ElementRef
    videoPlayerRef!: HTMLVideoElement
    video$!: Observable<any>

    constructor(private service: VideosService) {
        this.video$ = this.service.getVideo()
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.video$.subscribe((base64: string) => {
            this.videoPlayerRef = document.createElement('video')
            let source = document.createElement('source')
            source.type = 'video/mp4'
            source.src = `data:video/mp4;base64,${base64}`
            this.videoPlayerRef.setAttribute('controls', '')
            this.videoPlayerRef.appendChild(source)
            this.player.nativeElement.appendChild(this.videoPlayerRef)
        })
    }

    playVideo() {
        this.videoPlayerRef.play()
    }
}
```

component.html:

Empty container

```
<div #player></div>
```